# Remove "Protected" text in title h1 of protected wordpress pages

Tags: php, wordpress

Had a search around and can't seem to find any options to do this, found quite a few posts on how to personalise the login page but nothing about removing the Protected text that is automatically added before the page title, anyone able to shed some light?

EDIT:

Found the answer here in the end http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-remove-private-from-private-pages, code as follows

```
function the_title_trim($title)
  {
    $pattern[0] = '/Protected:/';
    $pattern[1] = '/Private:/';
    $replacement[0] = ''; // Enter some text to put in place of Protected:
    $replacement[1] = ''; // Enter some text to put in place of Private:

    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $title);
  }
  add_filter('the_title', 'the_title_trim');
```

Comment: [Googling "wordpress protected"](http://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+protected) gave me [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/protected-post-personalizer/) as the first result. It says it will let you do this.

Comment: If you have found an acceptable answer please post it as an answer and accept it, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: Would have loved to but didn't have relevant permissions to answer my own post within 72 hours or something… now done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here in the end http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-remove-private-from-private-pages, code as follows

```
function the_title_trim($title)
  {
   $pattern[0] = '/Protected:/';
    $pattern[1] = '/Private:/';
    $replacement[0] = ''; // Enter some text to put in place of Protected:
    $replacement[1] = ''; // Enter some text to put in place of Private:

    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $title);
  }
  add_filter('the_title', 'the_title_trim');
```

Answer (score 17):

There are dedicated wordpress filters ('private_title_format' and 'protected_title_format') applied to the post title when the post visibility is set to private or protected and you should use that in your functions.php instead of replacing all post-titles:

```
add_filter( 'private_title_format', 'myprefix_private_title_format' );
add_filter( 'protected_title_format', 'myprefix_private_title_format' );

function myprefix_private_title_format( $format ) {
    return '%s';
}
```

Comment: That's the correct and much better way to do it. If one would just search for "Private" in title (like the others propose) it's not working for multilingual website and it is not future save, because WordPress might change "Private" to another word.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small plugin to do this: http://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-protected/

Comment: Link only answers are bad. Explain what your plugin does please.

Comment: Isn't it obvious what the plugin does?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly more efficient method to remove the prefix. This only filters the title when the post/page is private or protected instead of on every page/post. You can also replace the prefix with whatever text you want by changing the second parameter of the preg_replace function or appending it to the string of course :)

```
add_filter( 'private_title_format', 'my_private_title_format' );
add_filter( 'protected_title_format', 'my_private_title_format' );
function my_private_title_format( $format ) {
    return preg_replace('/(Protected:|Private:)/','','%s');
}
```